How to create custom authentication
I want to migrate my React/Java application into Blazor Server application. Therefore, I have to create custom authentication.
In Java, I use JWT Token whenever the users login using their own username and password. When I migrate it into Blazor Server, I expect to use Cookies instead.
FYI, I want to create an application that have APIs as well, so I can scale up in the future, allowing users to use APIs as well instead of only on my portal.
My backend code structure will be Service -> Controller
In the frontend, right now for authentication, I will call API.
Here is my table Users.
[Table("USERS")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Column("created_by")]
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Column("created_date")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [Column("last_modified_by")]
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [Column("last_modified_date")]
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    [Column("activated")]
    public bool? Activated { get; set; }
    [Column("email")]
    public String? Email { get; set; }
    [Column("integration_token")]
    public String? IntegrationToken { get; set; }
    [Column("password")]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    [Column("user_system")]
    public String? UserSystem { get; set; }
    [Column("username")]
    public String Username { get; set; }
    [Column("iw_account_id")]
    public long? IwAccountId { get; set; }
    [Column("scheduled_time")]
    public String? ScheduledTime { get; set; }
    [Column("scheduler_enabled")]
    public bool? SchedulerEnabled { get; set; }
    [Column("sso_enabled")]
    public bool? SsoEnabled { get; set; }
    [Column("use_credit_invoice")]
    public bool? UseCreditInvoice { get; set; }
    [Column("extra_fee_percentage")]
    public double? ExtraFeePercentage { get; set; }
    [Column("use_all_in_one_invoice")]
    public bool? UseAllInOneInvoice { get; set; }
}

Here is my table UserRoles
[Table("USER_ROLES")]
public class UserRoles
{
    [Key, Column("user_id", Order = 0)][ForeignKey("Users")] public long UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Roles")][Column("role_id")] public long RoleId { get; set; }

    public Users Users { get; set; }
    public Roles Roles { get; set; }
}

AuthService.cs
public async Task<bool> ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
{
    var user = await _userRepository.FindByUsernameIgnoreCaseAsync(username);
    if (user == null) return false;

    // TODO: Implement proper password hashing and verification
    //return user.Password == password;
    return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, user.Password);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaimsForUser(Users user)
{
    var roles = await _userRepository.GetUserRoleNamesAsync(user.Id);
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString())
    };

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

    }

    return claims;
}

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.cs
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
    _logger.LogInformation($"User: {user.Identity.Name}");
    if (user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        return new AuthenticationState(user);
    }

    return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
}

public new void NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Notify Authentication State Changed");
    base.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task);
}

AuthController.cs
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest model)
{
    if (!(await _authService.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password)))
    {
        return Unauthorized(new { message = "Login unsuccessfully" });
    }

    var user = await _userRepository.FindByUsernameIgnoreCaseAsync(model.Username);
    var claims = await _authService.GetClaimsForUser(user);

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true, // Make the cookie persistent if needed
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30) // Set cookie expiration
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);


    return Ok(new { message = "Login successfully", user = new { user.Id, user.Username } });
}

Login.razor
@page "/"
@code {
private async Task LoginUser()
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Attempting to log in user: {Username}", Input.Username);
        var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/authenticate/login", Input);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Logger.LogInformation("API response status code: {StatusCode}", response.StatusCode);
        Logger.LogInformation("API response content: {Content}", responseContent);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            AuthStateProvider.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(
                Task.FromResult(await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync())
            );
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
        }
        else
        {
            //showError = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during login for user: {Username}", Input.Username);
        errorMessage = "An unexpected error occurred.";
    }
}
}

Home.razor
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger.LogInformation("Start to get authenticate state async");
    var authState = await CustomAuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    Logger.LogInformation($"authState at home.razor: {authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated}");
    if (!authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
    }
}

Here is the log when user clicks sign in
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7298
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5262
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\oscar.le\Desktop\Oscar\MiddlewareApps\C#\Integrations
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.Home[0]
      Start to get authenticate state async
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.Home[0]
      authState at home.razor: False
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.App.Authentication.Login[0]
      Attempting to log in user: halopsav2
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (32ms) [Parameters=[@__ToLower_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [u].[id], [u].[activated], [u].[created_by], [u].[created_date], [u].[email], [u].[extra_fee_percentage], [u].[integration_token], [u].[iw_account_id], [u].[last_modified_by], [u].[last_modified_date], [u].[password], [u].[scheduled_time], [u].[scheduler_enabled], [u].[sso_enabled], [u].[use_all_in_one_invoice], [u].[use_credit_invoice], [u].[user_system], [u].[username]
      FROM [USERS] AS [u]
      WHERE [u].[username] = @__ToLower_0
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[@__ToLower_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [u].[id], [u].[activated], [u].[created_by], [u].[created_date], [u].[email], [u].[extra_fee_percentage], [u].[integration_token], [u].[iw_account_id], [u].[last_modified_by], [u].[last_modified_date], [u].[password], [u].[scheduled_time], [u].[scheduler_enabled], [u].[sso_enabled], [u].[use_all_in_one_invoice], [u].[use_credit_invoice], [u].[user_system], [u].[username]
      FROM [USERS] AS [u]
      WHERE [u].[username] = @__ToLower_0
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[name]
      FROM [USER_ROLES] AS [u]
      INNER JOIN [Roles] AS [r] ON [u].[role_id] = [r].[id]
      WHERE [u].[user_id] = @__userId_0
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.App.Authentication.Login[0]
      API response status code: OK
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.App.Authentication.Login[0]
      API response content: {"message":"Login successfully","user":{"id":60014,"username":"usernametest"}}
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      Notify Authentication State Changed
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.Home[0]
      Start to get authenticate state async
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: Integrations.Components.Pages.Home[0]
      authState at home.razor: False
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:
info: CustomAuthenticationStateProvider[0]
      User:

So my workflow now is that when the user goes to my application, it will check if this user has been signed in or not, if not, it will redirect the user to /login.
If the user logins successfully, they will be able to go to homepage ("/").
You can see from the log that the API response status code is OK and API response content:
{"message":"Login successfully","user":{"id":60014,"username":"usernametest"}}.

Then it will go to Home.razor (log: Start to get authenticate state async) and call function var authState = await CustomAuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() in CustomAuthenticationStateProvider, however, this function still returns nothing on User.
I don't know where I have done wrong. Hope that you guys can point out.

Please show us evidence of any debugging you have attempted.

At the moment this is just a wall of code that I'm guessing no one has the time or inclination to try and piece together.  Auth is notoriously fickle, and very hard to answer questions on.  There any many. many questions on here that contain the two words "Custom" and "Authentication".  Almost all go unanswered.  Maybe, try and simplify your question??

could you share your program.cs file here. check the browser network tab to see if the cookie still persist after user login.  Use SignInAsync properly to persist cookies and make sure that the CustomAuthenticationStateProvider reads from the current HTTP context. make sure that the cookie isn’t expiring prematurely. have you tried clearing browser cookie and cache and try again to login. Make sure HttpContextAccessor is correctly injected and used in the custom authentication state provider. add some logging code to verify if the claims are correctly set after SignInAsync
